# If $(h_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is a sequence of non-negative simple functions s.t. $h_n\uparrow {1}_A$, then $A_n\uparrow A$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(h_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of non-negative simple functions and $1_A$ the indicator function on a measurable set $A$, and suppose that $h_n\uparrow 1_A$. Then, let $1 > \epsilon > 0$ and define $A_n = \{\omega \in \Omega\mid h_n(\omega) > 1 - \epsilon\}$. Then, why does $h_n\uparrow 1_A \implies A_n \uparrow A$? My reading material states this without really giving it a second thought. To my understanding, each element of the sequence is defined to be $h_n = \sum_{i=1}^{j_n}a_i 1_{A_i}$ for some finite values $a_1,\dots,a_{j_n}$ and measurable sets $A_1,\dots,A_{j_n}$.

Comment: Prove that $A_n \subseteq A_{n+1}$  and that $\bigcup A_n=A$. The fact that $h_n$'s are simple functions is not relevant.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Ah, I see. The assertion follows from $h_n \leq h_{n+1}$.